Performance Tuning an Informatica Mapping which has one Insert and 3 Update Logic
I have An Informatica Mapping which has one insert pipeline and 3 Update pipeline , all using an Update Strategy Transformation . The session stats shows that there is an target bottleneck . The commit interval in informatica is set to default value 10,0000 . Can any one help me in giving advise on how the performance tuning can be Done to Improve the session completion Time . For example can the commit interval can be Increased ? . We have 7 Index defined on the Target EDWH table , Does Dropping the index and recreating it increase the Performance ?



Informatica is clearly indicating the issue with the writer here. I don't thing changes in commit interval can change this much. The 7 indexes are the clear bottleneck: DB has to update all of them while inserting data.
I'd recommend dropping the indexes as part of the pre-SQL and re-creating as part of the post-SQL step. Results need to be tested, as the whole process takes around 7 minutes I'm not sure how much can be squeezed out of it.

clearly UPDATE is the problem. Dont drop all indexes blindly. Now, check what is the Primary key mentioned in Infa target. Ifyou have a DB index on that column(s), retain that index and drop others. If you dont have an index on that column, consider creating it. You can drop it after loading. Also, ensure stats on that table is updated in DB

Hi Koushik! Do note the insert is taking 2.5 minutes to process just 400 rows. This doesn't seem fast either. But of course your comment is 100% valid - testing various index dropping would shed some light here.

hmm, its difficult to tell because transactions occurs in batch, it can be like 10000 updated and then 1 inserted. But i agree, consider multiple scenarios and take actions accordingly.

Good point. Even though updates use separate connection, such high commit interval may result in misleading timing.
